# Read in all the files in a particular directory displays the file names in a html list in java

Tags: java, html

```
package fileBrowser;

import java.io.File;

public class Filewalker {
String str="";
public void walk( String path) {
File root = new File( path );
    File[] list = root.listFiles();
    int numfiles=list.length;
    for (int i=0;i<list.length; i++ ) {

        if ( list[i].isDirectory() ) {
            System.out.print("<li><span>"+list[i].getName()+"</span>\n<ul>");
                if(list[i].listFiles().length==0){
                System.out.println("</ul>\n</li>");
                continue;
            }
            walk( list[i].getAbsolutePath());
        }
        else {
            System.out.println( "<li>"+list[i].getName()+"</li>" );
                    if(i==numfiles-1){
                    System.out.println("</ul>");

                }

        }
    }
}


public static void main(String[] args) {
    Filewalker fw=new Filewalker();
    System.out.println("<ul>");
    fw.walk("C:/test");
    System.out.println("</ul>");

}

}
```

**the nesting of the folders in the ul list is not proper if the the folders have many nested folders**
when the the method is returning from the inner most folder the closing of the li tag is not happening 
the output that i am getting is:

```
<ul>
<li><span>abc</span>
<ul><li><span>ced</span>
<ul><li>New Microsoft Publisher Document - Copy (2).pub</li>
<li>New Microsoft Word Document - Copy (2).docx</li>
<li><span>test</span>
<ul><li><span>inner</span>
<ul><li><span>inner2</span>
<ul><li>New Text Document.txt</li>
</ul>
<li>New Bitmap Image.bmp</li>
</ul>
<li>New Microsoft Publisher Document.pub</li>
<li>New WinRAR ZIP archive.zip</li>
</ul>
<li>New Microsoft Publisher Document - Copy.pub</li>
<li>New Microsoft Publisher Document.pub</li>
<li>New Microsoft Word Document - Copy.docx</li>
<li>New Microsoft Word Document.docx</li>
</ul>
<li>temp1.txt</li>
<li><span>xyz</span>
<ul><li>stud11.txt</li>
<li>temp.txt</li>
</ul>
</ul>
```

Comment: I edited my answer to working and tested code.

Comment: If any answer helped you or solved your problem, vote it up and/or mark it as answered, please ;-)

Answer (score 1):

```
System.out.print("<li><span>"+list[i].getName()+"</span>\n<ul>");
            if(list[i].listFiles().length==0){
            System.out.println("</ul>\n</li>");
            continue;
        }
```

This code looks like the problem

You open `<li>` and `<ul>` but close it only if the directory is empty.

Comment: i close it here :else {
            System.out.println( "<li>"+list[i].getName()+"</li>" );
                    if(i==numfiles-1){
                    System.out.println("</ul>");

                }

        }

Answer (score 0):

As StanislavL in an answer wrote before, you open tags, but don't close them.

I cannot give you more hints in addition to your code, but would split your listings in 2 functions. Here's my try **(tested!)**:

```
public class ListFiles {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        File root=new File("./../");
        System.out.println("<ul>");
        printDir(root);
        System.out.println("</ul>");
    }

    static void printDir(File dir)
    {
        if(!dir.isDirectory())
            return;

        System.out.println("<li>" + dir.getName() + "</li>");
        System.out.println("<ul>");
        for(File file : dir.listFiles())
        {
            if(file.isFile())
                printFile(file);
            else
                printDir(file);
        }
        System.out.println("</ul>");
    }

    static void printFile(File file)
    {
        if(!file.isFile())
            return;

        System.out.println("<li>" + file.getName() + "</li>");
    }

}
```

`printDir()` prints and lists any directory. If a file is found inside the actual directory, `printFile()` is called to only print one line with the file name. Generally the single `println()` in `printFile()` can be moved into `printDir()` and you won't need an extra function for this, but if you want to print more information to a file, you have a better overview.

**Executing this results in:**

> - ..
>   - ListFiles
>     - .classpath
>     - .project
>     - .settings
>       - org.eclipse.jdt.core.prefs
>     - bin
>       - ListFiles.class
>     - src
>       - ListFiles.java

Maybe it helps you :-)

Answer (score 0):

You should really consider using the new Files API available in Java 7. It makes your job MUCH easier. Sample code (UNTESTED, but should do the job):

```
public void printDirectoryToStdout(final Path dirBase)
    throws IOException
{

    System.out.println("<ul>");

    Files.walkFileTree(dirBase, new FileVisitor<Path>()
    {
        @Override
        public FileVisitResult preVisitDirectory(final Path dir,
            final BasicFileAttributes attrs)
            throws IOException
        {
            System.out.printf("<li><span>%s</span>\n<ul>\n", dir.getFileName());
            return FileVisitResult.CONTINUE;
        }

        @Override
        public FileVisitResult visitFile(final Path file,
            final BasicFileAttributes attrs)
            throws IOException
        {
            System.out.printf("<li>%s</li>\n", file.getFileName());
            return FileVisitResult.CONTINUE;
        }

        @Override
        public FileVisitResult visitFileFailed(final Path file,
            final IOException exc)
            throws IOException
        {
            throw exc;
        }

        @Override
        public FileVisitResult postVisitDirectory(final Path dir,
            final IOException exc)
            throws IOException
        {
            if (exc != null)
                throw exc;
            System.out.print("\n</ul>\n</li>\n");
            return FileVisitResult.CONTINUE;
        }
    });

    System.out.println("</ul>");
}
```